# SkipEnabledCheck on logger message generator

Tags: c#, logging

Please see the following code which makes use of compile-time logging source generation:

```cs
public static partial class LoggerExtensions
{
    [LoggerMessage(
        EventId = 1953,
        EventName = nameof(Processed),
        Level = LogLevel.Debug,
        Message = "Processed {Count} records.",
        SkipEnabledCheck = true)]
    public static partial void Processed(this ILogger logger, int count);
}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger) => _logger = logger;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        _logger.Processed(42);
    }
}
```

This is the related `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the log message `Processed` shall only be logged if the `Debug` log level is enabled - which works perfectly fine.

However, I'm confused about why this actually works  from my understanding, the source generator converts the logging code to:

```cs
public static void Processed(this ILogger logger, int count)
{
    if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
    {
        logger.LogDebug("Processed {Count} records.", count);
    }
}
```

By setting `SkipEnabledCheck = true`, this should become:

```cs
public static void Processed(this ILogger logger, int count)
{
    logger.LogDebug("Processed {Count} records.", count);
}
```

However, if my assumption would be correct, the log statement should also appear when the minimum log level is set to `Information` rather than `Debug` because the necessary check is missing. But this is not the case, it gets only logged when setting the log level within `appsettings.json` to `Debug`.

What am I missing? ‍♂️

Thx!

Comment: Your question is about the internal implementation of SkipEnableCheck -- and it does not work as expected... so you assumption is wrong.  You can validate that easy enough, the source for C# is in the public domain, you could just go and look.